# How to generate maven pom with maven-publish gradle plugin after migrating to BOM

Tags: android, gradle, maven-publish, maven-bom

I was using the following for generating pom with maven-publish plugin in my build.gradle :

```
configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
    if (it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified" == it.name) && it.version != null) {
        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
    }
}
```

which was working great when using dependencies as follow :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
```

but not anymore after migrating to BOM :

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
```

which do not get versions (and thus do not include dependencies) while publishing :

```
> Task :vendor:generatePomFileForPublication
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.google.firebase', name='firebase-bom', version='26.0.0', configuration='default'}
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.google.firebase', name='firebase-config', version='null', configuration='default'}
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.google.firebase', name='firebase-messaging', version='null', configuration='default'}
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.google.firebase', name='firebase-analytics', version='null', configuration='default'}
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.google.firebase', name='firebase-crashlytics', version='null', configuration='default'}
```

Does one knows how to read versions from the BOM using gradle DSL ?
Or how to generate the dependencyManagement part of the pom.xml to reflect the BOM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decided to import BOM under dependencyManagement in generated pom.xml

```
google(MavenPublication) {
    groupId 'group'
    artifactId 'artifact'
    version android.defaultConfig.versionName
    artifact(sourceJar)
    artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/my-release.aar") {
        extension 'aar'
    }
    pom.withXml {
        def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
        def dependenciesManagementNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencyManagement').appendNode('dependencies')
        configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
            if (it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified" == it.name)) {
                if (it.name.endsWith("-bom")) {
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesManagementNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('scope', "import")
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('type', "pom")
                } else {
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    if (it.version != null) {
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great question and great answer - I have exactly the same problem, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @avianey The `if` condition is not correct, because if name is `null` it will never equal to "unspecified", also if name is NOT `null` the second part will never be reached, because `true` condition was already reached. That's why "unspecified" may also pass the condition. I think better will be `(it.name != null && "unspecified" != it.name)`